# Reuse tablecell in static table view - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reusability

I'm new and learning swift

I want to use static cells in my table view. I have all cells look similar so I thought of using xib for tablecell and use that in my static table view.

Problem I'm facing currently is, when I try to access label that i have in xib is throwing me error in method: ConfigureCell in below code.
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
Why is it saying im unwrapping optional when I dont have one

Not sure what needs to be done here/ Please advice.

below is my code:

```
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.tableView.register(ReusableTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"custom")
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 4
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom", for: indexPath) as? ReusableTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.configureCell(title: "Name", detail: "hello")
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            cell.configureCell(title: "Age", detail: "23")
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            cell.configureCell(title: "Dept", detail: "HR")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
class ReusableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var leftLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rightLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configureCell(title: String, detail: String) {

    leftLabel.text = title //Error Here: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

    rightLabel.text = detail

}
```

}[image]

Comment: Could you add the error contents and which line of code throws it?

Comment: Just added. It is in configure cell method

Comment: I just added your configureCell function to my own custom cell class which also has two labels, and also called it from within cellForRowAt from within the UITableViewController and it worked fine. I'm digging a little deeper now, but that function and how you're calling it aren't the issue

Comment: From the ReusableTableViewCell class, try to set two labels values from within awakeFromNib and see what happens. rightLabel.text = "right label test" leftLabel.text = "left label test", make sure that the cell.configureCell function call is commented out in the tableViewController for this test so that you're only setting the labels from within the ReusableTableViewCell class.

Comment: Actually in a **static** table view all cells are not reused. They are designed *statically* in the table view. The datasource methods are not used. As the cells are static you can access UI elements via `IBOutlet`s

Comment: I added in my awakeFromNib butthey aren't showing in my tableView. override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.leftLabel.text = "Hello"
        self.rightLabel.text = "World!"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with this line:

```
self.tableView.register(ReusableTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"custom")
```

Replacing that with the below solved the issue:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReusableTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
```